# typoscript exclude language parameter canonical tag

Tags: typoscript, canonical-link

I've got a question with my typo3 canonical tag.

thats my code:

```
tmp.canonical = TEXT
tmp.canonical {
  typolink.parameter.data = TSFE:id
  typolink.returnLast = url
  wrap = <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.myurl.com/|" />
}
page.headerData.3750 < tmp.canonical
```

what I want to do now is cut out the language parameter(e.g. http://www.myurl.com/abc?id=191&L=1).

my result at the moment is an canonical tag like:

> href="http://www.myurl.com/Unternehmen.191.0.html?&L=1"  />

but I want one like:

> href="http://www.myurl.com/Unternehmen.191.0.html?&"  />

How can i check if there is a language parameter and how can I delete it if there is one(there is not a languageparameter on every page)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stdWrap.replacement` with regex to cut it out, however this will really confuse the search engines and your visitors and will most likely have a very negative effect on your SEO.